# Adding only a certain number of the same object to an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a project where I am adding objects to an array when the user taps the object in my UITableView. The user can add multiples of a single object, but no more than 4. I can't figure out how to stop the object from being added if there are already 4 in the array. Is there a way to check how many of a single object are stored in the array?

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (![deckArray containsObject:[cardArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]] || [deckArray containsObject:[cardArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]] ) {

        [deckArray addObject:[cardArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

}
```

Comment: You have to store the object id & number of taps for that object in an NSMutableArray or NSUserdeafults. 

So for  each tap you can check the number of taps ,increment the number of taps relevant to that object , limit if it exceed 4 ..

Comment: Use an `NSCountedSet` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your conditional statement is always true. It says: "if the deck does or does not contain the object then add it."

Here is an inefficient way to do this is. It is slow because you need to enumerate every card in the deckArray, but if that array will never be very large (say 100 elements), then this is good enough:

```
id card = [cardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
int count = 0;
for( id deckCard in deckArray )
{
    if( [deckCard isEqualTo:card] )
        count++;
}

if( count < 4 )
    [deckArray addObject:card];
```

If the order of deckArray does not matter, you could use [NSCountedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCountedSet) and have a very quick way to check how many times you've added the card:

```
// somewhere else, deck is declared as:
NSCountedSet * deck = [NSCountedSet set];

// somewhere else
id card = [cardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if( [deck countForObject:card] < 4 )
    [deck addObject:card];
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!!

Comment: NSCountedSet seems like a good way to go. I was going to suggest that but you beat me to it.